# NoMethodError: undefined method `submission' for HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, httparty

I'm currently working on a Rails application where I am trying to submit a form to the FormStack API. The request look as follows.

This is what the requests looks like:

```
POST /api/v2/form/12345/submission.json HTTP/1.1
Host: www.formstack.com
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_APP_OAUTH_TOKEN
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

field_12345=Example&field_12346=Answer
```

I'm trying to implement that using Httparty on the library I created to make the requests to this API service.

```
module FormStack

 class Form
    include HTTParty
    attr_reader :form_id
    base_uri "https://www.formstack.com/api/v2"

    def initialize
      @access_token = ENV.fetch('FORMSTACK_ACCESS_TOKEN')
      @form_id      = ENV.fetch('FORMSTACK_FORM_ID')
    end

    def create_form
      self.class.get(relative_uri, headers: headers)
    end

    def submission
      self.class.post(create_submission_uri, headers: headers, query: query)
    end

    private

    def relative_uri
      "/form/#{@form_id}/field.json"
    end

    def create_submission_uri
      "form/#{@form_id}/submission.json"
    end

    def headers
      {
        "Accept" => "application/json",
        "Content-Type"  => "application/json",
        "Authorization" => "Bearer #{@access_token}"
      }
    end

    def query
      {
        "field_66563890" => "blah",
        "field_66563757" => "something"
      }
    end
  end
end
```

## controller

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  def display_form
    @form = FormStack::Form.new().create_form
  end

  def create
    @form.submission
    redirect_to 'localhost:3000'
  end
end
```

This are the routes

```
get '/forms/display_form', to: 'forms#display_form'
post '/forms/submit', to: "forms#create"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I've got a couple general ruby things for you:

1. When you call `FormStack::Form.new().create_form` you actually don't need the `()` after `.new` -- ruby knows to call the method with no arguments even if you exclude the parens.
2. I'm not quite sure how you're calling `FormsController::display_form` from `FormsController::create`, but for now I'll just assume that you're using magic.

Anyways, on to my answer. As your error message states, the error is related to you calling `submission` on something which does not have a `submission` method. With that knowledge, we can look at what Object you're calling submission on in this line:

```
@form.submission
```

It looks like you're calling `submission` on `@form`. Well, let's go and look at where you declare `@form`:

```
@form = FormStack::Form.new().create_form
```

Let's break that declaration down into its parts. First, with `FormStack::Form.new()`, you're creating a new instance of `FormStack::Form`. So far so good. `FormStack::Form` has a `submission` method defined on it. But then, you call `create_form` on it. So, let's look at what `create_form` does:

```
def create_form
  self.class.get(relative_uri, headers: headers)
end
```

`create_form` calls a method provided by HTTParty, `get`. The `get` method returns a `HTTParty::Response` Object. So, let's parse through the line where you set `@form` again. Broken down, what you're doing is this:

```
@form = FormStack::Form # This line sets the variable to a constant
@form = @form.new # This line sets the variable to be an instance of FormStack::Form
@form = @form.create_form # This line sets @form to be an instance of HTTParty::Reponse
```

As you can see, at the end we've set `@form` to an instance of `HTTParty::Reponse` instead of `FormStack::Form`, and since there's not `submission` method for `HTTParty::Response` that's why you get the error.

Based on this exploration, we can see that the fix would be to set `@form` to a `FormStack::Form` object instead, which we can do by changing the `display_form` action to be:

```
def display_form
  @form = FormStack::Form.new
  @form.create_form
end
```

Comment: thats a great explanation. One of the things you pointed out and that I'm doing wrong is the `display_form` action in the controller. I try using RESTful methods, but `index` or `show` didn't seem to fit what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: `show` seems to be what you want, but in order to really assess that, I'd have to see more of the code. If your code is working, but you're looking for ways to make it neater/more RESTful, you could try a question on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).